# Visual Studio 2010 + SDK 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-sdk

Is it possible to install VS SDK 2008 to use with VS2010 without installing VS2008?

Thank you.

Comment: Any specific reason you want to use the VS 2008 SDK?

Answer (score 0):

No, visual studio 2010 was completely rewritten in WPF. You are going to need VS 2008 to test anyways...

Comment: I'm building the project with VS 2010 and this project depends on VS 2008 SDK. On my machine I have installed both VS 2008 and VS2010 along with SDK's and everything works great. But my goal is to build the project on machine with minimal VS set installed(The best case is VS2010 + VS 2008 SDK). It looks like VS 2008 SDK asks me to install VS 2008 even if higher version (VS2010) is already installed.

Comment: I'd download [VS 2010 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=47305cf4-2bea-43c0-91cd-1b853602dcc5&displaylang=en) and upgrade your project to use it or leave the whole project in 2008

Comment: I can't upgrade the project to VS2010 SDK, since it is VS addin and I need to get it working with all VS versions starting from 2005.

Answer (score 0):

No. Visual Studio SDK's are tied to a specific version of Visual Studio. What you're attempting (while you may get it to work with some clever hacks) is not a scenario supported by Microsoft.